# How to write structure to file using fwrite without unnecessary characters (Null)

Tags: c++

I just can't get some user imputed data, to be stored in a file. 
I tried:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fstream>

struct persons
{
    char name[10];
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
} a[30],b[30],p;

int n,i;

int main()
{   
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile=fopen("data.int","w");
    cout<<"Number of persons: ";cin>>n;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        /*cout<<"Person: "<<i<<": "<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin>>a[i].name;
        cout<<"Day (dd): ";
        cin>>a[i].dd;
        cout<<"month (mm): ";
        cin>>a[i].mm;
        cout<<"Year (yyyy): ";
        cin>>a[i].yyyy;
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(a),1, pFile);*/
        cout<<"Persoana: "<<i<<": "<<endl;
        printf("Enter Name, day(dd), month(mm) and year(YYYY)\n");
        scanf("%s %d %d %d",a[i].name,&a[i].dd,&a[i].mm,&a[i].yyyy);
        fwrite(&a,sizeof(a),1,pFile);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I need in my file to have only the persons, on each separated line, in the order: name (space) dd (space) mm (space) year (eol).
Instead I have a huge line in which at some point I can see the values entered before.
I had read other topics regarding the usage of fwrite, but it still gives me the undesired Null values. 
Any hints?

Many thanks,

Comment: This is not `C`, its `C++`

Comment: well, beside the cout and cin functions, it is C. Either way, it does not matter so much how you show or read the user inserted values...

Comment: If you want formatted output, use fprintf, not fwrite.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: ok, I'll try. My problem is that I have a lot of "junk" in my file, not only the needed data. I want a function which could write each line from my structure into one line in my file, but I just can get that function right.

Comment: Do you have Linux machine accessible? `man fprintf`. Basic difference is `fwrite` - writes a chunk of bytes to a file given where as `fprintf` would write a formatted string, you can add '\n' at the end.

Comment: Your loop should be `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`, not `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`

Comment: `fprintf(pFile, "%s %d %d %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].dd, a[i].mm, a[i].yyyy);` will give the desired output.

Comment: "well, beside the cout and cin functions, it is C." There is no such thing. C++ is not an add-on to C, it's a separate language. You cannot have a function written partly in C and partly in C++. `<iostream.h>` is not a part of either C or C++ in any case.

Comment: @n.m.: sorry for my mistake. We're having a stupid teacher (if it possible to be called teacher) and in his courses he mixed up the syntax for C and C++ to the point I cannot tell one from the other.